# Integrating $e^{-x^4}$ with a trick?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

A classic trick to evaluate $I=\int_0^\infty {e^{-x^2}dx}$ is to consider $I^2 = \iint e^{-r^2} r dr d\theta$ and compute it that way yielding $\sqrt{\pi}$.

So, I'm wondering if I can extend this technique to higher even powers. In particular I'd like to compute $I=\int_0^\infty {e^{-x^4}dx}$ by considering

$$
I^4 = \iiiint e^{-r^2} d^4r =\int_0^\infty \int_0^\pi \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} r^3 e^{-r^2} \sin^2(\phi_1)\sin(\phi_2)d\phi_3d\phi_2d\phi_1dr = \pi^2
$$

This would *seem* to mean $I=\sqrt{\pi}\approx 1.77245$ as well. However, putting the original integral into Wolfram Mathematica, it claims $I=2\  \Gamma(\frac{5}{4})\approx 1.8128$.

My question is where my technique went wrong. Did I set up the integral wrong? Is the trick of considering $I^4$ not allowed in this case? This seems like a very cool technique and I'm eager to know whether it works or not.

Comment: Note that it's still $r^2$ in exponential, not $r^4$ like you want.

Comment: That's true but the integral is still doable by substituting $u = r^2$ so you get $\sim ue^{-u}$ which can be integrable by parts.

Comment: A problem is that $x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4$ cannot be written in terms of $r=\sqrt{\sum_ix_i^2}$ alone. Or in terms of $r_1=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ and $r_2=\sqrt{x_3^2+x_4^2}$, if using that kind of a variant of 4-dimensional spherical/polar coordinates.